# Django check whether all instances of a related object contain a certain value

Tags: django, django-templates

Here is my `models.py`:

```
APPLICATION_STATUS = (
        ('Pending', 'Pending'),
        ('Shorlisted', 'Shortlisted'),
        ('Not Shortlisted', 'Not Shortlisted'),
    )

class Vacancy(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Applicant(models.Model):
    year = models.IntegerField(default=datetime.date.today().year)
    vacancy = models.ForeignKey(Vacancy, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='applicants')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=APPLICATION_STATUS)
```

So I'm trying to check whether all the applicants' `status` for a particular vacancy are **NOT** Pending in the template but I can't work around it.

This is my template so far:

```
{% for vacancy in vacancies  %}                     
    <tr>
        <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
        <td>{{vacancy.vacancy_number}}</td>
        <td>{{vacancy.name}}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{vacancy.applicants.count}}</td>                           
        <td>
            {% if vacancy.applicants.count > 0 %}
                {% if vacancy.closing_date < today %}
                    [<a href="{% url 'shortlisting' vacancy.id %}">Shortlist</a>]
                    {% else %}
                    Vacancies are still active  
                {% endif %}
                {% else %}
                No applications for vacancy
            {% endif %}

        </td>
    </tr>             
{% endfor %}
```

How do I check if:

```
vacancy.applicants.status != "Pending"
```

Just a rough idea of what is to be implemented.

I know I can get all the related applicants of a particular vacancy using `vacancy.applicants` but I can't work around checking whether the statuses for those applicants is pending or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django doesn't allow filtering in a template so you either have to do it in your view or use a template tag.

You can use annotation in your view:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

vacancies = Vacancy.objects.all().annotate(pending_count=Count("applicants", filter=Q(applicants__status="Pending")))
```

Now if `pending_count` is 0, then it means that the Vacancy instance has no applicant with status pending.

```
{% if vacancy.pending_count == 0 %}
    <p>None of the applicants are pending ...</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to iterate over the `Applicants` for a particular `Vacancy` and check the, one-by-one, use:

```
{% for applicant in vacancy.applicants.all %}
    {% if applicant.status != "Pending" %}
        <!-- do something here -->
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

or if you want to just check whether all the applicants' `status` for a particular `vacancy` are not Pending, and you need a **Yes/No** answer in the template, add a **property** in your `Vacancy` model as follows:

```
class Vacancy(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    @property
    def check_all_applicant_status(self):
        return self.applicants.exclude(status='Pending').exists()
```

and in your **template**:

```
<p>{% vacancy.check_all_applicant_status %}</p>
```